# How to print out specific username by using "last" command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line

I know very basic of shell. I'm looking for a command to show the login of the specific user?
As I researched cut is eliminating the column of the output but I want to show only row with specifi command?

My current using command is:

`$last -a -n 100` (Now I want to add where user name = cvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grep the result:

```
last -a -n 100 | grep "^cvc"
```

This will filter those results of `last -a -n 100` that start with `cvc`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you explain what is "^" doing?

Comment: `^` ("caret") refers to the beginning of the line. This way it will match lines starting with `cvc` but not those that for example have `hello cvc`.

Comment: If you are done, you can consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes Thanks for that. I was waiting for considered time to accept the answer by the website